How to unify the legend with points only?
I am trying to plot the loess fit curves in each of sub-figures. There are three models and each model will have a color to represent. The code to generate the plot is as follows,
mydata1 <- data.frame("model" = rep("A", 1000), "n" = sample.int(10, 1000, replace = T), "n1" = seq(1,1000), "values" = rnorm(1000))
mydata2 <- data.frame("model" = rep("B", 1000), "n" = sample.int(10, 1000, replace = T), "n1" = seq(1,1000), "values" = rnorm(1000))
mydata3 <- data.frame("model" = rep("C", 500), "n" = c(rep(6,100),rep(7,100),rep(8,100),rep(9,100),rep(10,100)), "n1" = seq(1,500), "values" = rnorm(500))
mydata <- rbind(mydata1, mydata2, mydata3)

fig_list <- list()
for (i in sort(unique(mydata$n))) {
   data <- mydata[mydata$n == i, ]
   fig_list[[i]] <- ggplot(data, aes(x = n1, y = values, colour = model)) +
           geom_point(size = 0.6, show.legend = TRUE) +
           scale_color_discrete(limits = unique(mydata$model)) +
           labs(title = paste0("n = ", i), x = "n1", y = "values") +
           theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 10)) + 
           geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.3, fill = "lightskyblue", level = 0.95) 
}

fig_all <- ggarrange(
     plotlist = fig_list, ncol = 2, nrow = ceiling(length(fig_list) / 2),
     common.legend = TRUE, legend = "top"
)
annotate_figure(fig_all, top = text_grob(paste0("All the plots are here.")))

However, if I use the code above, the legend of the models are mixed with lines and point, while I want all three to show points of different color. How can I unify the legend to show three models with points rather than mixed lines and point?


This question is similar to: Legend fails to show a category in ggplot when this category only has partial values. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Edward as the same user asked the other question, I'm going to guess they mean something different by each question

It's a different question. The curves are loess fit rather than the lines that connect the actual data points. Moreover, my question is how to have the legend unified here as you can see on the top, the model A and model B are represented by lines, but model C is a dot. I want three models to be shown with dots of different colors. Thank you!

This can also be done with facetting. By the way, @Phoebe, you didn't accept any of the previous answers.

I need to use this ggarrange to visualize the plot, so can't use facetting. I accepted both the previous answers.

Does n=1 have to be the first plot (at the top left), or can these be reversed so that n=10 is first?

It would be the best if n=1 can go first...

The current method is somewhat flawed since ggarrange takes the first plot in the list to construct the combined legend, but for n=1, there is no model C, so that is omitted in the legend. A workaround is to create the legend separately, using the whole dataset, extract it using get_legend, and combine it with the main plots.
library(ggpubr)

p1 <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x = n1, y = values, colour = model)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.3, fill = "lightskyblue", level = 0.95) +
  theme(legend.position="top")
my_legend <- get_legend(p1)

fig_all <- ggarrange(
  plotlist = fig_list, ncol = 2, nrow = ceiling(length(fig_list) / 2)
)

p2 <- annotate_figure(fig_all, top = text_grob(paste0("All the plots are here.")))

p <- ggarrange(plotlist = list(as_ggplot(my_legend), p2), 
               nrow = 2, heights = c(1,10))
annotate_figure(p, top = text_grob(paste0("All the plots are here.")))



Make sure to specify , show.legend = FALSE in the for loop for BOTH geoms (geom_point and geom_smooth).

Thank you so much! I am able to reproduce the figure that you generated! Thank you! It seems like p2 is not necessarily needed.

Yes - sorry. Just ignore that. If this answers your question, remember to accept (green tick)

Just did. :) Thank you very much again!
